# how to speedup following sed command

Tags: macos, unix, sed

I have nearly 6000 files to edit using following sed command. its taking longer time.

does any one have an idea how to make following commands faster.

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/old word/new word/g' {} \;
```

Comment: If not does one have any other command to edit(replace particular word) in faster way

Answer (score 4):

Similar to @JonathanLeffler's strategy of running one invocation of sed for multiple files, but you can also use xargs to run multiple threads in parallel, taking advantage of multiple processors.

```
find ./ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 100 -P 8 sed -i .bak -e 's/old word/new word/g'
```

Comment: I wonder how much benefit you get from parallelism like this. Clearly, the compute part works faster, but the dominant factor is likely disk I/O and running multiple processes in parallel on the same file system is likely to be hitting the same disk controller, and therefore the improvement is likely to be small, unless the kernel grabs space for I/O buffers so that most of the work is done in memory and the disk catches up later. On Linux, the GNU [`parallel`](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) program can be used to do parallel access (it is mostly an `xargs` drop-in replacement, IIRC).

Comment: And my questioning comment is not in any sense intended to disparage this answer; it is a fine answer.

Comment: Thanks. :)  It depends on the IO capacity, and how many threads you try to run. It's true you can overload it if you're not careful, and that will cause queueing. But you can probably get some degree of parallelism out of it. No point in starting more threads than the number of cores you want to employ, though.

Answer (score 3):

There is really only one way to speed it up and that is to make it execute `sed` less often, which you do by replacing the `\;` with `+`.  This makes `find` group file names up to a convenient limit, roughly like `xargs` would do, but without the nuisances of having to rely on GNU `-print0` and `-0` options (to `find` and `xargs` respectively — though they are also available in the BSD `find` and `xargs` available on Mac OS X).  It is also POSIX standard notation.

Note that you are making backups of your affected files with the suffix `-e` because the Mac version of `sed` insists on an argument for the `-i` option, and the `-e` happens to be there to be used, and the script does not have to be prefixed with `-e`.

Hence, this command should work faster:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i .bak -e 's/old word/new word/g' {} +
```

How much faster is more debatable.